# Don't allow users to close the docusign document without signing it

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with a php codeigniter application. I have embeded  docusign in my application. My questions is can i disable the close button on the top of the document. So that users are not allowed to close the document without signing in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to disable the Close button, and there never will be.  Think about what you are asking:

- You are sending an electronic signature request to someone, asking for their legally binding signature on a document.
- Once they open, you want to make it so that they can't close without signing the document.

This is a form of coercion, it's like holding a gun to someone's head forcing them to sign a document saying they owe you $1,000,000.  The DocuSign service will never allow this and will always allow people to decline to sign.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to disable the close button within the DocuSign envelope.  Even if it were possible to do so, it's never going to be possible to force a user to complete any task within your application.  i.e., a user could do any of the following at any time:

- exit/close your application altogether without signing the document
- walk away from their computer/device without signing the document
- lose internet connectivity rendering them unable to complete signing & submit the Envelope
- shut down their computer/device altogether without signing the document

Disabling the Close button would do nothing to keep any of these things from happening.